# Keras does not show progress bar arrow while training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano

At first, I was running keras with tensorflow backend, and the progress bar was fine. Then I installed Theano, and tried using it for a while before switching back to tensorflow. After installation of Theano, the progress bar that appears at each epoch only comes up as after the epoch is done, so while it's training, I don't see its progress.

```
Epoch 1/50
21/21 [=============================] 10s - loss:0.6928 - loss_val: 0.6912
```

I want it to show the progress while it is training, like this:

```
Epoch 1/50
21/21 [=====>.......................] 10s - loss:0.6928 - loss_val: 0.6912
```

Why does it change the progress bar format after installing theano, and how can I change it bak to showing the progress?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using:

```
 model.fit(.....,.....,....,verbose=1)
```

The verbose variable is used for showing training progress. You can look at the Keras documentation:

> verbose: 0 for no logging to stdout, 1 for progress bar logging, 2 for one log line per epoch.